# how Is Convergence of machine learning bounded O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, machine-learning

All charts of machine learning performance (y-axis:accuracy 0.0-1.0) across epochs have the below shape.  Is there any research that explain how this convergence is bounded O(n) where n is the number epochs (and ultimately the number of examples the algorithm visits).

[image]

Comment: This does not look at all like a logarithmic shape.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Thanks for the note. I rephrased.   Would logistic be a better fit?

Comment: Depends how exactly you define it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand for Neural networks depending on the optimization method used Stochastic gradient Descent or Nesterov Acelerated Descent the convergence is bounded by $O (1/k)$ and $O(1/k^2)$ respectively.  This is expressed in terms of loss reduction e.g. how quickly can the algorithm reduce error, where k is the number of iterations it takes for the algorithm to achieve it.

To describe the above chart that is performance overtime rather than loss reduction.   We could say $1 - O(1/k)$ since 1.0 is considered the upper perfect learning scenario.

See https://angms.science/doc/CVX/CVX_FoM_tight_rate.pdf